# sql - calculating the price of an order and sum of all orders on a receipt

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I have three tables as follows:

MenuItem

```
MenuItemID   ItemName   ItemPrice
X0001        LatteSmall   $15
X0002        LatteBig     $18
X0003        MochaSmall   $16
```

Orders

```
OrderID MenuItemID ReceiptID`
O000001 X0001      R000001
O000002 X0002      R000001
O000003 X0001      R000002
O000004 X0003      R000003
```

Receipt

```
ReceiptID ReceiptPrice
R00000001 ???????????
R00000002 ???????????
R00000003 ???????????
R00000004 ???????????
```

What I am trying yo do is: Calculate the price of each order, and then sum up orders that belong to each receipt. List the summed up values in the `ReceiptPrice` field on the `Receipt` table.

How do I do this with a single query on Microsoft Access 2010?

Any help is appreciated =))

Comment: If you got a helpful solution, please remember to vote it, and mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: Noted, thanks William!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample data you have provided it's a little hard to tell, but I assume that each receipt may contain multiple orders.

The following query will return each order on each receipt with a total menu item cost per order. This assumes that `ItemPrice` is numerical, and doesn't actually contain the '$' character, maybe you could confirm that?

```
SELECT O.ReceiptID, O.OrderID, SUM(MI.ItemPrice) AS TotalReceiptPrice
FROM Orders AS O INNER JOIN MenuItem AS MI ON O.MenuItemID = MI.MenuItemID
GROUP BY O.ReceiptID, O.OrderID
```

If you wish to only see the total for each receipt, including multiple orders, then try this;

```
SELECT O.ReceiptID, SUM(MI.ItemPrice) AS TotalReceiptPrice
FROM Orders AS O INNER JOIN MenuItem AS MI ON O.MenuItemID = MI.MenuItemID
GROUP BY O.ReceiptID
```

Comment: There indeed can be multiple orders on each receipt. And the dollar sign is auto-added by the Currency display format. What I get when I run this query I get multiple entries for the same Receipt. I wish to sum all orders on a receipt together, in the same query.

Comment: @Daturk Try the query in my edit, that should give you one total per receipt, regardless of the amount of orders.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Lastly, is there a way for me to write the `TotalReceiptPrice` on the `ReceiptPrice` attribute of the `Receipt` table? Do you think that's a wise thing to do?

Comment: Sure, you would perform an `UPDATE` based on the value we just selected, like in Gordon Linoff's answer, whether this is wise or not depends. For example, can a receipt total can change over time, when do you perform the `UPDATE`? Just food for thought. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the database.  Here is one way:

```
update receipt
    set receiptprice = (select sum(itemprice)
                        from menuitem inner join
                             orders 
                             on menuitem.menuitemid = orders.menuitemid
                        where orders.receiptid = receipt.receiptid
                       );
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when I run this query, other than fixing the typo at `menuitem.menutitemid`, i see no other solution. Could you check?

Comment: @Daturk . . . The only other error I see is `inner join` -- MS Access likes the word "inner".